# Electrical reactance : physical inertia analogy

Tags: physics

Would electrical reactance and physical inertia be appropriate general analogies?  Each is a resistance to change.  I've thought of trying to construct a table of similarities between disciplines to speed and clarify understandings as courses seemed to converge on these evaluations.

Comment: These are quite common analogies. Inductance is like a flywheel, capacitance is like a spring. Both are forms of energy storage. BTW, when I was an undergrad, I rather amusingly discovered from mech eng friends that their lecturers used electrical analogies to explain second order mechanical systems. I guess it is just a way of broadening perspective.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about.  I found an explanation of electrical reactance as a generalized term for both capacitors and inductors and I know mass' inertia is the resistance to change in motion. I was additionally e.g. trying to correctly relate a concept of "thermal inertia" (heat capacity) to mass inertia; heat conductance with electrical resistance; mass as "energy condensate".  I thought there might be better uniform correlations than current engineering typically gives effort toward.  I find some of those examples not clear, overlapping and inconsistent (no personal offense meant).

Answer (score 2):

> I've thought of trying to construct a table of similarities between
>   disciplines

Why bother when there are plenty on the web: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.vias.org/matsch_capmag/matsch_caps_magnetics_chap1_20.html)

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.hydraulicspneumatics.com/technologies/hydraulic-electric-analogies-part-1)

[image]

[Picture source](https://physiology.kitware.com/_circuit_methodology.html)

There are literally loads of them if you search "electrical and mechanical equivalent table".

Comment: Thanks, but I just don't find those at all parallel.  Force and current the same? No. At least force and voltage.  If they are, then I am not recognizing the concepts correctly.

Comment: @LouF they are interchangeable. Pressure can be regarded as voltage and if that pressure causes movement then movement can be regarded as current. In a magnetic circuit, current (amps x turns) can be regarded as equivalent to voltage (huh I hear you say). I tend to regard a flywheel like a capacitor but in different analysis scenarios it can be regarded as a spring.

Answer (score 1):

> Would electrical reactance and physical inertia be appropriate general analogies?

Yes, a mass-spring system has exactly the same energy, impedance, displacement, force equations as an LC system has energy, impedance, charge and voltage equations.

Constructing a table of all the equivalent variables is a good way to learn and explore.

There are plenty of examples on the web to cross-check your work as you progress.

Take care to match pressure-like things as voltage and pressure, displacement-like things like distance and charge, and speed-like things like current and speed, to get the best correspondence between mechanical and electrical.